# Explicit nullable types and where != null

Tags: c#, nullable-reference-types

When using the new explicit nullable reference types features in C# 8.0 (all types must be explicity declared as nullable if they are to be set to null https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references ), how do you handle the following situation:

Say you have some function that returns an IEnumerable of `Something?`

```
var result = aFunction()
         .Where(data => data != null)
         .Select(data => data.Id).ToList();
```

the data.Id is shown as an error (I have warnings as errors turned on):

[image]

because it can be null, even though it is checked to be not null by the Where.  I don't want to have to supress the error in this case, is there a way to handle this syntactically?

Comment: you're asking a subjective question here.  What have you tried? have you tried `data.HasValue` in where clause, and `data.Value.Id` in Select/Projection/Map?

Comment: nullable reference types do not have HasValue

Comment: i fail to see why this is subjective

Comment: I get no warnings and looks fine in my test project (Visual Studio 2022, .Net 6, console project)

Comment: that will be because you don't have "nullable" enabled. its a relatively new feature see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references.  Also need warnings as errors to create an error.  It removes the risk of null reference exceptions.

Comment: I have it and I am very aware of it.   <Nullable>enable</Nullable>

Comment: I think in this specific case you have to manually say data is not-null: `Select(data => data!.Id)` I don't think the compiler figures this out\

Comment: The phrasing 'How do you handle the following situation' struck me as subjective, but perhaps that is debatable.  Give me a second to review on this claim of not having `HasValue` for an explicitly nullable reference type in regards to this feature.. I may be misunderstanding something here.

Comment: @Bizhan which is basically suppressing the warning but i think that is the answer. I wasn't aware of that ! notation.  Its syntactilly neat.

Comment: You can try `aList.Where(data => data != null).OfType<Something>().Select(data => data.Id).ToList();`

Comment: try `var result = aList.Select(data => data?.Id).Where(id=>id.HasValue).ToList();`

Comment: This works for me... https://dotnetfiddle.net/ofj2AQ

Comment: i've updated the answer, I had over simplified it from my code

Comment: right, so nullable reference is different then I understood it to be..  after review, I would handle this scenario using *null-forgiving operator* `data!.Id` (as the documentation states) for these dereferenced "maybe-null" scenarios.

Comment: side note: `data != null` *doesn't actually mean that `data` is not `null`*; you can construct a type that will genuinely throw a NRE in this case (i.e. `data` can still be `null`); to check "data is not null", without needing to ask "what is this type? how does it behave?" you should really use the test `data is not null` (in recent C# versions, at least; you can do similar in older C# versions, but it is more verbose)

Comment: example: https://sharplab.io/#v2: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

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler is not "smart" enough to detect that the argument to `Select()` cannot be null in this case, as it only does static code analysis. For situations like these, the ! notation was introduced with nullable reference types. Applying an exclamation mark to an object tells the compiler to "shut up" about nullability warnings.

```cs
var result = aFunction()
         .Where(data => data != null)
         .Select(data => data!.Id).ToList();
```

This means that the compiler will not generate a warning that `data` could be null. This is helpful in all cases where you know that the value is not null, but the compiler (e.g. due to the complexity of the code) doesn't properly detect that.

Note that this really only removes the warning. If the value is, in fact, null, the code will behave as previously, so it would throw a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I will probably use this, however, for absolute certainty of not getting null reference exceptions using OfType<Something> in the above example appears to work in all cases with no null reference exceptions.

Comment: Yes, but it also adds complexity. My answer points to the generic use of the exclamation mark, as it can also be helpful outside of linq queries (e.g. with nullable fields that you know are not null within some method).

Comment: with that snippet.. I don't think you would receive a null reference in the first place, Tim.  The solution here is resolving the compiler static analysis warning.  That warning is only an error because you're treating warnings as errors.  and yea, introducing complexities -- with `OfType` -- seems unwarranted.

Comment: also, nullable-reference-types for the language feature is a bit more relevant/scoped for this discussion (then the link in the question).  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-reference-types